# Get the second highest salary of the employees using LINQ

Tags: c#-3.0, linq-to-entities

I have the following entity

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public long Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to find out the second highest salary for the employees of every individual department using LINQ.

So far here is what I have done

```
 var Query = (from emp in Employees
              orderby emp.Salary descending
              group emp by emp.Department into g
              select new
              {
                  id = g.Select(i=>i.EmployeeID),
                  sal  = g.Select(s=>s.Salary),
                  name = g.Select(n=>n.EmployeeName),
                  dept = g.Select(d=>d.Department)
              }

              ).Skip(1).ToList();
```

But this query is not working.,

E.g.

Suppose I have

```
EmployeeID = 1,EmployeeName  ="A", Department ="Dept1", Salary = 10000
EmployeeID = 2,EmployeeName ="B", Department ="Dept1", Salary = 20000
EmployeeID = 3,EmployeeName ="C"  Department ="Dept1", Salary = 20000
EmployeeID = 4,EmployeeName="D",  Department ="Dept1", Salary = 30000
EmployeeID = 5,EmployeeName  ="A1", Department ="Dept2", Salary = 12000
EmployeeID = 6,EmployeeName ="B1", Department ="Dept2", Salary = 4500
```

The expected output will be

```
EmployeeID = 2,EmployeeName ="B", Department ="Dept1", Salary = 20000
EmployeeID = 3,EmployeeName ="C"  Department ="Dept1", Salary = 20000
EmployeeID = 6,EmployeeName ="B1", Department ="Dept2", Salary = 4500
```

in the result set

Using C#3.0 and Dotnet framework 3.5

Comment: "But this query is not working" In what way is it not working?

Comment: I am not able to get the correct output. I have to bind this to a datagrid(windows application) where only the department names are coming with this query. I need to show all the relevant records like EmployeeID, EmpName, Department, Salary

Comment: I think the query currently skips the first department, not salary. You're probably going to have to run a sub-query against each department.

Comment: What would you want the result to be if there's more than one person with the top salary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which is your desired behavior so here are two versions.

```
//select people with second person's salary
var q = from emp in Employees
        group emp by emp.Department into g
        let salary = g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Salary).Skip(1).First().Salary
        let second = g.Where(e => e.Salary == salary)
        from emp in second
        select emp;
```

```
//select people with second highest overall
var q = from emp in Employees
        group emp by emp.Department into dept
        let seconds = dept.GroupBy(e => e.Salary).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).Skip(1).First()
        from emp in seconds
        select emp;
```

Comment: The query works but if suppose I have

EmployeeID = 1,EmployeeName  ="A", Department ="Dept1", Salary = 10000
EmployeeID = 2,EmployeeName ="B", Department ="Dept1", Salary = 20000
EmployeeID = 3,EmployeeName ="C"  Department ="Dept1", Salary = 20000
EmployeeID = 4,EmployeeName="D",  Department ="Dept1", Salary = 30000

The query returns only one 2nd highest salary record and not both(as in this example)

Comment: Ah duplicates.  Though Jon has a point.  I'll update to match your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access right now to a C# compiler, but this should work:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
foreach(var grouped in db.Employees.GroupBy(p=>p.Department))
{
    if (grouped.Count() > 1)
    {
        int tmpSalary = grouped.OrderByDescending(q=>q.Salary)
            .Skip(1).Take(1).Single().Salary;
        employees.Concat(grouped.Where(q=>q.Salary == tmpSalary));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//select people with second person's salary DEPARTMENT WISE

var R = from          m         in x
        group               m by m.Department into g
        let              sal = g.GroupBy(w=>w.Salary).OrderByDescending(w=>w.Key).Skip(1).First().Key
        let          xz = g.Where(w=>w.Salary==sal)
        from       m in xz
        select m;

Answer (score 0):

This query should solve your purpose:

```
var employees = from emp in employeeList
                group emp by emp.Department into g
                let salary = g.GroupBy(e => e.Salary).OrderByDescending(e => e.Key).Skip(1).First().Key
                let second = g.Where(e => e.Salary == salary)
                from emp in second
                select emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Linq. I have taken duplicate salaries in consideration too.
I have working solution at [Linq: Nth Largest Salary](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yt2DLX)

```
private static List<Employee> GetLargestSalary(List<Employee> employees, int nThPosition)
{
    // Write your logic here.
    var salaries = employees
        .GroupBy(s=>s.Salary)
        .OrderByDescending(s=>s.Key) // Grouping by salary to handle duplicate salaries
        .Skip(nThPosition - 1) // Skipping n-1 salaries to get nth salary.
        .First()
        .ToList();
    
    return salaries;
}
```